# what is CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_FACING in AWS ip_range.json?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to find a way to determine Cloudfront Origin Shield IP ranges and was wondering if by any chance it could be "CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_FACING" service from https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json ?

There are quite a few overlapping ranges from different services, its hard to just test this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, while there is no official confirmation in the documentation, I can't think of any other service with the above [service code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-syntax).

`CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_FACING` can only be referring to Amazon CloudFront Origin Shield.

Overlaps are fine, AWS can & will reuse IPs for various services.

Comment: I will try, and come back here if it happens to be something else ^^

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/limit-access-to-your-origins-using-the-aws-managed-prefix-list-for-amazon-cloudfront/
"You can filter the prefixes from ip-ranges.json with the service code values CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_FACING and CLOUDFRONT respectively."

Comment: That said another documentation only talks about "CLOUDFRONT": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html